# Adobe AIR trialware creating method

Tags: apache-flex, air, registration, activation, trialware

I am creating a window application by using Adobe AIR .I want to make it as trial ware.But I don't know how to achieve this.Please suggest some ideals or link for my reference.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of options for licensing schemes within Flex:

1. Build your own solution.
2. Take a look at [NitroLM](http://nitrolm.com/) which offers a licensing scheme for AIR.
3. Take a look at [Sharify](http://www.sharify.it/); which offers a licensing scheme for AIR
4. Take a look at [Zarquon](http://zarqon.net/), which offers a license scheme for AIR

Comment: +1. With the demise of Adobe AIR marketplace, it's leaving more of us to do this sort of research on our own. I knew about the 1st, but not the other two. Now, if we could just get these guys to explicitly state using our system with x users will cost you $y (this).